# How can I import other dart file to stateful widget in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and trying to learn it.

I have main.dart in lib, HomePage.dart in lib>ui>screens, and Widgets.dart in lib>ui>widgets.
I imported the HomePage.dart to main.dart, and what I want is importing Widgets.dart to HomePage.dart.

HomePage.dart contained stateful widget, and Widgets.dart contained some widgets and a stateful class.

Below is the part of code.

///main.dart///

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'ui/screens/HomePage.dart';
import 'ui/screens/AnalysisPage.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'covid-19',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => HomePage(),
        '/analysis': (context) => AnalysisPage(),
        //'/news': (context) => NewsPage(),
        //'/more': (context) => MorePage(),
      },
      //home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

///HomePage.dart///

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:covid_app/ui/widgets/Widgets.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String data = '';

  fetchFileData() async {
    String responseText;
    responseText = await rootBundle.loadString('lib/assets/number.txt');

    setState(() {
      data = responseText;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchFileData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    final Size size= MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    List<String> number = data.split(' ');

    return Scaffold(...)
```

///Widgets.dart///

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget _drawer(BuildContext context){
  return Drawer(...)

//More widgets in this file, but I'll skip it.

class ClassificationCircle extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _ClassificationCircleState createState() => _ClassificationCircleState();
}

class _ClassificationCircleState extends State<ClassificationCircle> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(...)
```

Thank you for reading, and I'll wait for your advice!

[file structure !click me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvP2a.png)

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are asking. You are already doing several imports. Can you please clarify what is your specific problem with context?

Comment: oh, sorry. Um I tried to import Widgets.dart file with "  import 'package:covid_app/ui/widgets/Widgets.dart';   " in HomePage.dart, but it doesn't work.

Comment: or should I add something more in pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: what does not work

Comment: there are some widgets like _drawer in Widgets.dart file, but in HomePage.dart file which I wrote " import 'package:covid_app/ui/widgets/Widgets.dart'; ", it doesn't work. ((I'm not an English user, so sorry for my English. it may be hard to understand..))

Comment: You are still not telling us what doesn't work. Please be specific. When you call the classes you get an error? The import gives an error? By the way, you should use the Dart file naming convention "lowercase_with_underscores": https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-libraries-and-source-files-using-lowercase_with_underscores

Comment: it said 'unused import' and ''The method '_drawer' isn't defined for the type '_HomePageState''.

Comment: I added a file structure image in my question.

Comment: please remove "_" from starting of  widgets name and then try to use that widget

Comment: and always create widgets as class file that will be easy to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove "_" from starting of your widgets name

if you append "_" before widgets name your widget acts as private.